# Setting Layout Background Changes Layout Size

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I have this XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.00"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3.2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/addtrials"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>  
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >



    </LinearLayout>  
            <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    </LinearLayout>  

    </LinearLayout>
```

Without setting the background layout, it was OK, but after setting the background, the layout height gets stretched and I don't know why that happens.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
 android:layout_weight="1" ,
```

if the image is of diferent size, All layouts are adjusted to new content.

Comment: the image forces layout to change its size not the vice versa